# expl3 with check-declarations turned on fails to compile if siunitx is loaded

Tags: siunitx, expl3

In my work with `LaTeX3` I like to turn on `check-declararations` as it identifies  variables I forgot to declare. However, `siunitx` complains, which causes a problem, I cannot do without `siunitx`!

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
Either I am using package expl3 inappropriately, or it's Hi Joseph!
\end{document}
```

Comment: As noted in answers, the `check-declarations` option is really there for code development. I will fix these two missing items in the next update.

Comment: Any context (link to an inside joke on meta...?) on how is a "Hi developer!" an euphemism for a bug/feature?

Comment: @matsmath ... goes straight over my head. I steer clear of 'meta', always. As an alternative to me having used expl3 incorrectly 'Hi Joseph' was simply an invitation for the developer to roll up his sleeves, which he promptly did!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, either disable the check again or add the two missing variables manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l__siunitx_per_two_parts_bool
\bool_new:N \l__siunitx_product_repeat_bool
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
Either I am using package expl3 inappropriately, or it's Hi Joseph!
\end{document}
```

The check is meant really for testing purposes only.

Answer (score 5):

It's “Hi, Joseph!”

The first error is due a typo in `siunitx.sty`. At line 4584 (release 2.6q dated 2016/03/01) the package has

```
\bool_new:N \l__siunitx_two_parts_bool
```

instead of

```
\bool_new:N \l__siunitx_per_two_parts_bool
```

The variable `\l__siunitx_product_repeat_bool` is indeed undeclared.